# Creating a large scrolling view in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uiscrollview

I want to create a large view that will contain about 10-20 fields (slides, datepicker, textfields), all aligned one under the other. 
I'm on Interface Builder and I've placed a UIScrollView and on top of that added some fields.
But I can't add any more fields that are not visible in the current window.

So, how do I go about to add more fields inside that ScrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the uiscrollview with your mouse and drag it up and the part that you cant see will be visible to you window. And so on and so on. Be sure its size is bigger than your view

Comment: Ok, it only works on occasions. I have to click the top window bar and then click on an empty space. If the UIScrollView is full of other views...there is no way to move it.

Answer (score 5):

Set the Simulated Size to Freeform and put large numbers in the height and width.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can also use your mouse scroll wheel anywhere in the tableview window to scroll up/down

Comment: The OP is not talking about a tableview.