# Adding a scrollbar to a ViewController (storyboard)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to add a scrollbar type mechanic to an app view.  From what I have looked for it at first seemed like a UIScrollView would be the optimal choice but now I am not so sure..

Basically all I want to do is be able to add numerous text boxes, sliders, and buttons etc into a view.  The problem is how many I need to add at any one time is determined based on user input so it is entirely possible the amount of objects I need to add to the view may not fit in just one screen.  All I need to do is to be able to scroll down further and allow the user to see the other input options.

Is this something the scrollview is used for?  If so, how do i drag/drop buttons/text boxes into the scrollview so they appear.. well, below the normal resolution so you must scroll down to see them.  When I attempt to drag/drop objects into the view controller I can't go below the normal size of the box.

I hope I explained this clearly enough.

Thanks.

Comment: If the number of items is user definable, why aren't you adding them at runtime?

Comment: Well, I will eventually.  I was just trying to test out the scrolling in the app by drag/dropping objects first rather than write up a whole slew of code to build the objects just to find out it won't scroll in the first place.  It was kind of a related, but separate question.

Comment: You should just be able to add it to the view first and then manipulate `x, y` coordinates of the frame to shove it off the initial view, causing it to scroll.

Comment: Ok, so would I even need a UIScrollView for that? or would just pushing the coords off the initial view auto create a scrollable view?  Also, is there a way to simulate that in drag/drop or do I have to manually edit the coords in code.

Comment: Well, I've tried adding both a text box and a button at Y coordinate 500 which is below the screen.  Both with a UIScrollView and without.  Neither automatically add any sort of scrolling option.

Comment: A normal `UIView` won't auto add scrolling. On the `UIScrollView` part, are you sure that the `UIScrollView` was still the parent of the view you added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. While a generic UIScrollView certainly can be used for what you want, in practice you may find that a UITableView fits better... you see a lot of "forms" are implemented in such a manner and lets you do things like access a field by indexPath.
2. To accomplish what you are trying to do, follow the instructions in [Scrolling through UIScrollView in Interface Builder for Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252503/scrolling-through-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder-for-xcode-4) - in short, you will create your embedded view inside the view controller's view, temporarily move it to the top of the view hierarchy for scrolling and control layout purposes, and move it back to the the view controller's view when finished.
3. You don't put views/controls in a *view controller* you put them in a *view* which is managed by a view controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tableviews only display text though right?  they don't allow for text boxes, buttons, and sliders etc to be input into them do they?

Comment: I'm also not really getting much out of your #2 about scrolling the UIScrollView.  Nothing I am doing seems to be working.  Dragging it to the 'top level' doesn't seem to do anything other than make the UIScrollView disappear, the View disappear, or nothing at all.

Comment: ok i figured out the resizing to see things offscreen that everyone was talking about.   Still no way to scroll to these objects below the screen during runtime though..

Comment: Tableviews can display anything you want if you create a custom UITableViewCell.  A UITableViewCell is just a UIView and can have subviews (including controls).  Scrolling performance problems can crop up if you have too complex a view hierarchy, but don't worry about optimization unless it becomes an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying about no scrolling during at runtime... are you saying that you created a scrollview but it won't scroll?

Comment: Yes Conrad.  I created a ViewController.  Added a UIScrollView to it, then placed a button below the visible screen.  Ran the app, and I cannot scroll down to see the button.  All of this was done drag/drop in xcode 4 using storyboards.

Comment: The more I look into the tableview the more I like that idea to be honest.  I'm still not 100% sure I want to go that route because I don't know if it can do all that I want to, so I still would like to get the UIScrollView working.  But the tableview is an interesting option.  I didn't know cells acted in such a way.

Comment: Most intro books cover using table views in that manner if you choose to go that route.  As for your scrolling issue, sounds like maybe you forgot to call -setContentSize: in your -viewDidLoad method?  (Somewhat bizarrely, Interface Builder does not allow you to set the scroll view's content size directly, it has to be done in code.)

Comment: Right.. I did not set that value because well.. the size can change depending on certain situations the app is not in control of.  Basically, the app will receive information with how many question to ask a user from an outside server it communicates with. I have no way of knowing how big or small the content will be.  If i set the content size to really large, but the content received is really small, would the user be able to scroll on tons of white space?

Comment: You *have* to set the content size for UIScrollView to know how much scrolling to permit.  In the situation you describe, you need to set it dynamically... when you receive content, calculate the new contentSize (using the known height of your controls, appropriate padding, etc.) and call -setContentSize: to update.  But really this is one reason why UITableView is useful.