# UIScrollView longer than VC

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been working with some `UIScrollView` objects that are longer than the view controllers they are contained by (this is in storyboard). Right now if I want to move objects that aren't initially shown I have to resize both the view controller and the scroll view. I also have to do this to add new objects to an initially non-displayed area. I know that I can do these things with the dimension inspector, but if I do that I can't tell what the layout looks like.

**Is there another way to do this?** I haven't been able to find a way to make the scroll view "scroll" inside of storyboard/IB. And it's kind of a pain to do layout this way.

Comment: I removed my answer as I was mistaken. Two finger dragging works for a static table view controller with more rows than will fit on the screen, but scroll view support in interface builder is pretty poor as far as I can see.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135163/how-do-i-use-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252503/scrolling-through-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder-for-xcode-4

Comment: @jrturton Thanks, I read the second one earlier. I saw that it was > 1 year old so it seemed like there might have been new features/discovery/better way to do it.